# How can I implement a fast install of git using sh?

Tags: macos, git, sh

I need to get a classroom full of students to install git on their computers quickly and during a lecture. I've been inspired by the installation process of meteor to try and implement something similiar, i.e:

```
curl easy-install-git.com | sh
```

I know there already exist binaries and easy ways to install git, but those are all multi-step processes and this would be one simple command in terminal. How do I write an sh script to do this? (Or better yet, does one exist already?)

Any other easy ways to do a git install on  a clean machine would also be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you expect the software to be installed?  Do you expect them to use `sudo` to install it?  Will it be on their PATH automatically?  There are ways of packaging arbitrary files as 'shell script' that self-extract; they aren't all pretty, but they do work.  I work on a Mac, but I don't login as the administrative user most of the time — which probably puts me in a tiny minority, but beware of the awkward squad. (Not that it stops me administering; I upgraded to 10.8.5 without switching to the administrative user, for example.  But I don't have `sudo` privileges — I just checked.)

Comment: They will have sudo privileges and I want it to act like a regular git installation when finished. It should be in their PATH, fully installed globally as usual.

Comment: The XCode command line utilities installs a version of `git` in `/usr/bin/git`.  Do they have XCode installed?  Can you just tell them to get the command line utilities?  (They may be only available to registered, paid-up Apple developers, so it is a genuine question.)  I upgraded recently; the Apple-provided `git` is 1.8.3.4, which isn't too far behind the current 1.8.4 release.  My own build is sloppily out of date — 1.7.7.308, it seems (it was; I just rebuilt to current 1.8.4). To install in `/usr/bin`, the `sudo` privileges will be necessary.

Comment: You can get git 1.8.3.2 from http://git-scm.com/download/mac.  It's a DMG file.  Are you sure repackaging on your own is easier than getting them to download an already packaged version that installs like everything else?  (Or like almost anything else; it is produced by an unidentified developer so you have to change the permissions temporarily to allow it to be installed: System Preferences ⟶ Security & Privacy ⟶ General, and change the 'Allow applications downloaded from' to 'Anywhere' (for as long as it takes to install `git`).

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, the easiest/fastest way to [install Git on Mac](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#_installing_on_mac) is to type:

```
git --version
```

> If you don’t have it installed already, it will prompt you to install it.

But that is an [old Apple fork of Git](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/) (2.10 at most)

The [`git-osx-installer dmg files`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/) are up-to-date, with Git 2.18.
As seen [in this script](https://github.com/nfaction/hb-cask/blob/master/pre-install.sh#L48-L67), it can be curl'd.